# Drawing the 3D curve $z=xy\sin(x^2+y^2)$ with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I drew the 3D curve `z=xy\sin(x^2+y^2)` with Mathematica as following

[image]

How can draw it with `TikZ`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Have a look at http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/surface-plot-math/ and http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/tufte-3d-axes/ as starters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%hide axis,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
colormap/blackwhite,
]
\addplot3[domain=-3:3,surf,samples=41]
{x*y*sin(deg(x^2+y^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: plot]